# Pandas Reversing the Dataframe and getting the first element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two questions:

1. I would like to reverse the order of the data loaded from the csv. Then get the time from the first row from the time column.
   After doing df = df[::-1], I expect the value 17:00:03 instead of 15:59:56.
   Where have I made a mistake?
2. how to use Pandas to round the value 17:00:03 to 17:00:00?

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('gold_16_12_2021.csv')
print(df['time'].head())
print(df['time'][0])
df = df[::-1]
print(df['time'].head())
print(df['time'][0])
```

Result:

```
0    15:59:56
1    15:59:55
2    15:59:55
3    15:59:32
4    15:59:30
Name: time, dtype: object
15:59:56
79199    17:00:03
79198    17:00:05
79197    17:00:07
79196    17:00:07
79195    17:00:07
Name: time, dtype: object
15:59:56
```

Expect result:

```
17:00:03 or 17:00:00
```

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple questions in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reset the index using [DataFrame.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) after reversing the order of the rows since the index doesn't get updated automatically. To round the second in the time, you can try using [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) convert the time string in each row to datetime object and then format that object to string as `%H:%M:00` (assuming you don't intend to round up the seconds if it's above 30) and then apply the result to either the `time` column or a new column (`round_time` in the below example)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')
print(df['time'].head())
print(df['time'][0])
df = df[::-1]
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print(df['time'].head())
print(df['time'][0])
df['round_time'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.strptime(row['time'], '%H:%M:%S').strftime("%H:%M:00"), axis=1)
print(df)
```